# How to keep inside body of html page fixed

Tags: jquery, css

When I re-sized my application window , my footer,body and header shrinks but i want to keep width and height same as a original, so when we re-sized window outside scroll appears and which keeps footer,body and header part remains same as original.
How can i do this...? Advance thanks...

```
#contentFrame {


    height: 74%;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 180px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y:visible;
    -ms-overflow-y: auto;
    /*   -ms-overflow-y: hidden; */ /*for ie8*/
    bottom:50px;
    width:auto; 
    right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set `width:###px` and `height:###px` attributes in the CSS for any (block) element on your page.

Comment: Hi mblase75: thanks for quick reply. but when we change resolution it does show properly.

Comment: roXon: Nah, I've been there. Sometimes it takes a while for people to learn the etiquette on a forum -- especially if they're (apparently) not native speakers of the language.

Comment: @roXon you are right but as mblase75 said sometimes it takes a while for some people...

Comment: Aaaya: please provide us with some sample code, possibly using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Never blind S.Overflow from entering codes. Post codes and help people answer to your question (depending on the progr. language you use) with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) DEMO of your issue.

Comment: I have added my ccs class used for body element. So when we re sized window from bottom, i want to keep my body element height and width same as original, and versicle and horizontal  scroll bar appear an which keeps height and width of header, footer and body fixed.

Comment: @mblase75 :Thanks for suggestion. I have calculated screen.availHeight at the time of body load and set in pixel. it solve my problem.                                                 `myWidth = screen.availWidth;
   myHeight =screen.availHeight; document.getElementById("contentFrame").style.height = (myHeight-350)+'px';`

Answer (score 0):

set the bounds for the header and footer div's in pixels. Also, use font in pixels if you want them to remain the same as well.

Comment: But if  we specify height and width in pixel and change to higher resolution of screen then all content appears very small.

Comment: Ah, now your question makes sense. In this case use relative sizes. em's pixels etc. These days the standard seems to be to set the default value of everything in percentage and then override it with `em`. This article may be useful. http://mondaybynoon.com/2006/03/13/effective-style-with-em/ in particular read the second "Uses Outside of Font"

Comment: :Thanks for suggestion. I have calculated screen.availHeight at the time of body load and set in pixel. it solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using the CSS property `min-width: #px`

Comment: :Thanks for suggestion. I have calculated screen.availHeight at the time of body load and set in pixel. it solve my problem.